# Adding columns without using left joins in SQL

Tags: sql, performance, join, teradata

In (Teradata) SQL I want to change the structure of a table. Currently I am using left joins but perhaps there is a more efficient way to do it.

The table contains processes related to packages with some process details. Instead of having a row for each process per package, I want a row per package and columns for each process and it's details.

I currently have a table structured as follows.

| Package number | Process | Startdate process | Enddate process |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Create | 1-1-2020 | 1-2-2020 |
| 1 | Deliver | 1-2-2020 | 1-3-2020 |
| 2 | Create | 1-1-2020 | 1-2-2020 |
| 2 | Deliver | 1-2-2020 | 1-3-2020 |
| 3 | Create | 1-1-2020 | 1-2-2020 |
| 3 | Deliver | 1-2-2020 | 1-3-2020 |

I want it to be as follows:

| Package number | Startdate creation process | Enddate creation process | Startdate deliver process | Enddate deliver process |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-1-2020 | 1-2-2020 | 1-2-2020 | 1-3-2020 |
| 2 | 1-1-2020 | 1-2-2020 | 1-2-2020 | 1-3-2020 |
| 3 | 1-1-2020 | 1-2-2020 | 1-2-2020 | 1-3-2020 |

Thanks!

Comment: You are describing a PIVOT operation, but under the covers the PIVOT operator is essentially conditional aggregation as in the answer suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what left joins have to do with this, but you can get what you want with conditional aggregation:

```
  select
  package_number,
  max(case when process = 'Create' then <start date column> end) as 
  startdate_creation_process,
  ...
  from
  ...
  group by
  package_number
```